# Размытие BorderBrush у Border

Tags: wpf, xaml

делаю форму из группы TextBox которые прижаты друг к другу.
[image: Вид общей разметки]

Пытаюсь добавить к ним изображение оформленное в такой же рамке, как и TextBox:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Background="Red" BorderBrush="#abadb3" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="demo.png"></ImageBrush>
                    </Grid.Background>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

В предварительной разметке выглядит всё правильно:
[image: Предварительный просмотр XAML]
Но при запуске происходит размытие цвета **#abadb3**. В чем ошибка?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Динамический просмотр XAML:

[image: 1]

Comment: "Размытие цвета"? Это как? И да, советую использовать векторное изображение, а не растровое, тогда не будет этих лесенок, пикселей, и так далее.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Добавил изображение правого верхнего края из динамического просмотра XAML, которое не соответствует предварительной разметке. Изображение взято случайное для демонстрации.

Comment: Если я скопирую ваш код, вставлю в чистый WPF проект, я получу это размытие?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ попробовал в чистом проекте и нашел причину,. Пробовал выставлять Height у Grid в целых и не целых числах, и соответственно получал этот эффект.

Comment: Пример в вопросе обновляйте, ибо мы уже час сидим с вами, без воспроизводящего примера. И зачем вы интересно забиваете размеры гвоздями, когда как правильней будет дать свободу UI...?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ изменил пример для чистого проекта WPF, контейнеры имеют свою относительное значение, без гвоздей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема возникала при появлении дробной части у `Width`, `Height`. Использование `UseLayoutRounding` решает эту проблему.